# NIFI: Best way to find the attributes used by processors

Tags: apache-nifi

I inherited a large nifi flow whose predecessor was enamored with the ExecuteScript processor.   As I review the scripts, they are setting custom attributes that are (sometimes) used later in the flow.   I've been laboriously examining each processor to track where these attributes are used.   However, this is quite labor intensive and I'm hoping there is a better way to determine what attributes are really used.   I realize this won't help if the custom attributes are used by other ExecuteScript processors, but it would reduce the search space if I could get a list attributes matched to the processors that use them.

I've tried using the REST api.   If I know the UUID for each processor I can programmatically get the json configuration and parse out the attributes from that.   However, I don't see an API call that will list all the processors and their UUIDs.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You can retrieve the provenance events for a processor using the REST API or in NiFi with a SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask, those events include attributes changed or added by the processor

Comment: if you still want to parse attributes from code - use `flow.xml.gz` as a source. it has all processors configuration.

Comment: look int nipyapi python module - it is easy to achive your task with it

Comment: @mattyb:   The provenance event API has the same problem as the processor API.   You need to know the UUID of the processor to get the information.

Comment: @dagget:   Good suggestion (and blindingly obvious in retrospect).    A quick grep of the XML answered my question.  Thanks!

Comment: @Up_one:  Interesting library.  I will look into that more deeply.  Thank you.